# Javascript match - include anything with 2 keywords, ignore anything with 1 keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I would like to include a string if it contains either 'jpg' or 'png' but exclude the string if it contains 'http'.

I have been trying the following but it still includes the string if it contains both http and either png or jpg:

`myString.match(/(?!http)(jpg|png)/i)`

An expected input would be `http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/1512491455764.png?Signature=signature`

As this contains both http and png, this string would be ignored / return false from the regex

Comment: Please share input and expected output.

Comment: `/^(?!.*http).*(jpg|png)/i`

Comment: I'm assuming you have some characters between http and jpg or png? Your regex should take that in consideration

Comment: @HassanImam updated with an example input

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank-you, that is now returning the correct result. I will mark it as the correct answer if you want to post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!.*http).*(jpg|png)/i
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*http)` - no `http` is allowed after any 0+ chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current location is allowed
- `.*` -  any 0+ chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current location
- `(jpg|png)` - either `jpg` or `png`.